# frame overflow visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, frame

I have a frameset on my site. Is it possible to set the overflow of one frame to visible, so elements of this frame are displayed over the other frame?

If not, could I append the elements to the parent document with Javascript and display them over the frames?

Thanks for your advise.

Comment: My advice is to stop using frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But if you want that one frame append other try `position: absolute;`. It would be cool if you have any online demo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you're trying to do but in general I can't see how a good site layout would require its elements to be overflown. There probably is a more elegant way to achieve the same thing.

But if you want or need to go that way, you will at least have to start replacing your frames by divs. Consider your current framed layout as a set of separate pages not "interacting" with each other. Using divs you put everything in to one single place and all your elements can overflow, overlap, or whatever.

Really, frames are a thing of the past in that regard.